# What do the first two lines of this rap by Public Enemy mean?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, public-enemy

The rap group "Public Enemy", in their second album *It Takes a Nation of Millions to Hold Us Back* (released in 1988), had a track titled [*Don't Believe the Hype*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Believe_the_Hype). Its first stanza is:

> Back
> Caught you lookin' for the same thing
> It's a new thing - check out this I bring
> Uh oh, the roll below the level
> 'Cause I'm livin' low next to the bass
> C'mon
> Turn up the radio
> They claim that I'm a criminal
> By now I wonder how
> Some people never know
> The enemy could be their friend, guardian
> I'm not a hooligan
> I rock the party and
> Clear all the madness, I'm not a racist
> Preach to teach to all
> 'Cause some they never had this
> Number one, not born to run
> About the gun...
> I wasn't licensed to have one
> The minute they see me, fear me
> I'm the epitome - the public enemy
> Used, abused, without clues
> I refused to blow a fuse
> They even had it on the news.
> ...
> Don't believe the hype

What is meant by the first line "caught you lookin' for the same thing"? More specifically, what 'thing' was being looked for and why?

Also, what is this 'new thing' that he's going to 'bring'?

What does he mean by 'don't believe the hype'?

Comment: Just FYI, this post has been flagged for closure as "too broad". I think it's fine to ask a general question about the meaning of the first few lines, but I'd suggest you edit out your query about "don't believe the hype" (which you could then ask in a new question instead).

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a rough gloss of the verses:

“Back” —> “we have returned with a second album”

“caught you lookin’ for the same thing” —> “we know you were expecting us to repeat our prior success with a more-of-the-same sophomore effort…”

“It’s a new thing” —> “… but we have advanced our artistic talents and political awareness”

(The above is merely my interpretation, but it’s similar to the [community gloss supplied by Genius.com](https://genius.com/Public-enemy-dont-believe-the-hype-lyrics).

Indeed, “caught you lookin’” is a good example of how PE had advanced: it accuses the listener of being complicit in a capitalist system that delivers bland pop music that exactly meets (but never exceeds) their expectations.  (Per the [Wikipedia article for the song](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Believe_the_Hype), Chuck D was reading Noam Chomsky around the time he wrote this song.). PE is trying to wake their audience up, open their eyes, and get them on their feet.